# Prevent ghost entries in many to many

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table **tags** with fields `tag_id` and `name`. I have a junction table **tag_map** with fields `tag_id` and `vid_id` that connects table **tags** to table **video** (via vid_id).

When I insert a new tag for a `vid_id`, I delete all my entries in tag_map for that `vid_id`, if there was only one entry in `tag_map` I also want to delete that tag in table `tags` to prevent ghost entries (tags entries without a corresponding tag_map entry).

The issue is, I cannot seem to accurately obtain this count. For example if I have 3 entries in `tag_map`, each having 1 corresponding tag in `tags`, I get count for each tag as 1,0,0. Am I using the wrong query for this purpose?

```
//find all tags for given vid_id
$sql = 'SELECT tag_map.*, tags2.name AS tag_name
FROM tag_map
INNER JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
INNER JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tag_map.vid_id=?';
$stmt_tags = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt_tags->execute(array($vid_id));

while ($row = $stmt_tags->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$tag_name=$row['tag_name'];

//for each tag check how many rows exist in tag_map COUNT IS NOT ACCURATE
    $sql = 'SELECT *, COUNT(tags2.name) as cnt
FROM tag_map
JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tags2.name=?';
$stmt_tags2 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt_tags2->execute(array($tag_name));

while ($row2 = $stmt_tags2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $cnt=$row2['cnt'];
}

if ($cnt==1){
  $sql = "DELETE FROM tag_map WHERE vid_id = ?";
$stmt14 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt14->execute(array($vid_id));
  $sql = "DELETE FROM tags2 WHERE tags2.name = ?";
$stmt14 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt14->execute(array($tag_name));
}
else {
      $sql = "DELETE FROM tag_map WHERE vid_id = ?";
$stmt14 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt14->execute(array($vid_id));
}
}
```

**EDIT for inserting into many to many**

```
foreach($variable as $tag) {

    $sql = 'SELECT *, COUNT(tags2.name) as cnt
FROM tag_map
JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tags2.name=?';
$stmt_tags2 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt_tags2->execute(array($tag));
while ($row = $stmt_tags2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $cnt=$row['cnt'];
    $exist_tag_id=$row['tag_id'];
}

$id=md5(uniqid());
$tag_id=md5(uniqid());

if ($cnt==0){
    $sql="INSERT into tag_map (id,vid_id,tag_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute(array($id,$vid_id,$tag_id));
    $sql="INSERT into tags2 (tag_id,name) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute(array($tag_id,trim($tag)));
}
else {
$sql="INSERT into tag_map (id,vid_id,tag_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute(array($id,$vid_id,$exist_tag_id));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't even need to worry about the count. Delete from tag_map and then:

```
DELETE t 
    FROM tags2 t
        LEFT JOIN tag_map tm
            ON t.tag_id = tm.tag_id
    WHERE tm.tag_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Joe, that is much more efficient than what I had. I edited my question to show how I am inserting tags after they have been removed. Would the count be necessary for the insert?

Comment: @Scarface: If you've created appropriate foreign key relationships between these tables (and if you haven't, do so now. You'll thank me later), then your first insert would fail since you can't insert into `tag_map` until all the tags first exist in `tags2`.

Comment: Thanks again Joe, I will definitely research into foreign keys and add that into my relationship. But how would I connect the `tag_map` tag_id to the `tags2` tag_id without first querying `tags2` to check that existing tag's tag_id?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do it like this? Or am I missing something?

Delete all tags from a certain video and then delete tags that have no corresponding value in tag_map table.

```
DELETE FROM tag_map WHERE vid_id = <video_id>;
DELETE FROM tags t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tag_map tm WHERE tm.tag_id = t.tag_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

In both of your queries, the join to video is unnecessary since you are only operating on vid_id. Just concentrate on the tags2 and tag_map table. With the extra join, you might get a false 0 if you didn't have a video entry for that tag.

Also, if you want to get a count for a specific tag_id, do the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(tm.tag_id) FROM tags2 t 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tag_map ON tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
  WHERE t.name = ?
```

Perform an outer join so that you'll actually get counts of 0 where there isn't an entry in tag_map for the tag.

However, I would prefer an actual DELETE like the one that checks for existence above.

Comment: I had not even thought of that, thanks a lot Kris. This answer was extremely helpful to me.